# Lightning component that allows you to paste from clipboard

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it currently possible to create a control that lets you paste from the clipboard? If so how? Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly but I’ve see an article online which describes some approaches using JS to achieve similar functionality  maybe will help https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f

Answer (score 1):

No. Modern browsers do not allow reading the clipboard for security purposes. They also don't allow copying *to* the clipboard unless triggered by a user action (e.g. onclick). See [this site](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=synchronous%20clipboard%20api) for details.